# Snap svg load inside load

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to load one svg inside another and with jquery append second svg element to first.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var s = Snap("#svgmain");
    var g = s.group();
    Snap.load("SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg",function(lf)
    {
        g.append(lf);//Added #svg3049 to #svgmain>g
        Snap.load("SVGFILES/info_msg.svg",function(lf_info_msg){
            g.append(lf_info_msg);//Added #svg2>path to #svgmain>g
            $("#svgmain > g > svg#svg3049 > g").append($("#svgmain > g > svg#svg2 > g"));//OK
            });
    //trying to append path from second svg element to first
    $("#svgmain > g > svg#svg3049").append($("#svgmain > g > svg#svg2 > g"));//NOT OK
    });
)};
```

Why I can't append path in the first function?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Check "SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg" 's source code, because Snap.svg fails to complete Snap.load method when target svg file has xml Declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap.load is asynchronous, so you can't be sure how long it will take to complete, which is why there is the callback function.

If you just run the append in the first function, the 2nd load will likely not have completed by the time it has run. So it will need to be within the callback of the 2nd function. That way you know both files have finished loading.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to load two or more svg files using only one Snap.load?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you wanted to use a plugin so you load some in order in one go though, you could use a loop, I wrote a couple at http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-loadmulti.html or http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-loadmulti-callback.html which could be of help.

Comment: Ok, but is there way to work with svg outside snap.load function?

Comment: You can't work with an SVG before its loaded. You can call another main func (which is written outside of the callback) from your callback function. So that only gets run once your files are loaded. That way you can separate the code from the callback, but it only gets executed via the callback. If that doesn't make sense, shout and I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I will try to use a loop. Thank you for your advices.